# Проблема с вёрсткой, доделка игры

Tags: javascript, css

Ребята, такая проблема, мне нужно доделать игру в адаптиве, и сделать так, что бы кнопки внизу не отступали сразу же от первого блока вопроса, а как только блоки вопроса достигнут кнопок ответов, сами блоки вопроса прописаны в JS, что делать?(Ссылка:http://gfsk8cdc.azurewebsites.net/)

Comment: Какая польза людям будет от вашего вопроса, если проблема по ссылке решится? Что останется будущим поколениям? Приведите проблемный фрагмент кода.

Comment: У вас лютая мешанина в стилях, позиционируете элементы отступами и через position: absolute. Почитайте о позиционировании элементов.